# sklearn, numpy, and pandas will not import Netbeans 9.0 OSX

Tags: python, pandas, netbeans, scikit-learn, netbeans-9

As the title says I am running Netbeans 9.0. I have Python 2.7 installed. I have pip installed and I ran all pip installation commands. I can see all installed files under `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages`, however I still get:

```
ImportError: no module name sklearn
```

Obviously there seems to be a disconnect between Netbeans and this folder. What do I need to do to make `netbeans` and `sklearn`, `pandas`, and `numpy` to work together?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it

Tools -> Python Platforms -> Python Path

Make sure you have the directory included where these applications are located.

in my case the directory is /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages